# Fragile rule application in Isabelle

Tags: isabelle, isar

I was playing around with an example from the Isabelle/HOL tutorial to get a better understanding on the correspondence between Isar and Tactics proofs.

This is a version which works:

```
lemma rtrancl_converseD: "(x,y) ∈ (r ^-1 )^* ⟹ (y,x) ∈ r^* "
proof (induct y rule: rtrancl_induct)
  case base
  then show ?case ..
next case (step y z)
  then have "(z, y) ∈ r" using rtrancl_converseD by simp 
  with `(y,x)∈ r^*` show "(z,x) ∈ r^*" using [[unify_trace_failure]]
    apply (subgoal_tac "1=(1::nat)")
    apply (rule converse_rtrancl_into_rtrancl)
      apply simp_all
    done
qed
```

I want to instantiate `converse_rtrancl_into_rtrancl` which proofs `(?a, ?b) ∈ ?r ⟹ (?b, ?c) ∈ ?r^* ⟹ (?a, ?c) ∈ ?r^*` .
But without the seemingly nonsensical `apply (subgoal_tac "1=(1::nat)")` line this errors with

```
Clash: r =/= Transitive_Closure.rtrancl 
Failed to apply proof method⌂:
using this:
    (y, x) ∈ r^*
    (z, y) ∈ r
goal (1 subgoal):
 1. (z, x) ∈ r^*
```

If I fully instantiate the rule `apply (rule converse_rtrancl_into_rtrancl[of z y r x])` this becomes `Clash: z__ =/= ya__`.

This leaves me with three questions: Why does this specific case break? How can I fix it? And how can I figure out what went wrong in these cases since I can't really understand what the unify_trace_failure message wants to tell me.

Answer (score 2):

`rule`-tactics are usually sensitive to the order of premises. The order of premises in `converse_rtrancl_into_rtrancl` and in your proof state don't match. Switching the order of premises in the proof state using `rotate_tac` will make them match the rule, so that you can directly apply `fact` like this:

```
... show "(z,x) ∈ r^*" 
  apply (rotate_tac)
  apply (fact converse_rtrancl_into_rtrancl)
done
```

Or, if you want to include some kind of `rule` tactic, this would look like this:

```
  apply (rotate_tac)
  apply (erule converse_rtrancl_into_rtrancl)
  apply (assumption)
```

(I personally don't use apply scripts ever in my everyday work. So apply-style gurus might know more elegant ways of handling this kind of situation. ;) )

---

Regarding your `1=(1::nat)` / `simp_all` fix:

The whole goal can directly be solved by `simp_all`. So, attempts with adding stuff like `1=1` probably did not really tell you a lot about how much the other methods contributed to solving the proof.

However, the additional assumption seems to actually help Isabelle match `converse_rtrancl_into_rtrancl` correctly. (Don't ask me why!) So, one could indeed circumvent the problem by adding this spurious assumption and then eliminating it with `refl` again like:

```
apply (subgoal_tac "1=(1::nat)")
  apply (erule converse_rtrancl_into_rtrancl)
  apply (assumption)
apply (rule refl)
```

This does not look particularly elegant, of course.

---

The `[[unify_trace_failure]]` probably only really helps if one is familiar with the internal workings of Nipkow's higher-order unification algorithm. (I'm not.) I think the hint for the future here would really be that one must look closely at the order of premises for some tactics (rather than at the unifier debug output).

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I try to stay with Isar but had enough problems trying to make induction rules apply that I feel some lower-level knowledge would help.
I later noticed that rule_tac and intro also work so it might be some edge case that the basic rule methods can't deal with.

Answer (score 0):

I found an explanation in the Isar reference 6.4.3 .

The `with b1..bn` command is equivalent to `from b1..bn and this`, i.e. it enters the proof chaining mode which adds them as (structured) assumptions to proof methods.

> Basic proof methods (such as rule) expect multiple facts to be given
> in their proper order, corresponding to a prefix of the premises of
> the rule involved. Note that positions may be easily skipped using
> something like from _ and a and b, for example. This involves the
> trivial rule PROP ψ =⇒ PROP ψ, which is bound in Isabelle/Pure as “_”
> (underscore).
>
> Automated methods (such as simp or auto) just insert any given facts
> before their usual operation. Depending on the kind of procedure
> involved, the order of facts is less significant here.

Given the information about the 'with' translation and that rule expects chained facts in order, we could try to flip the chained facts. And indeed this works:

```
  from this and `(y,x)∈ r^*` show "(z,x) ∈ r^*"
    by (rule converse_rtrancl_into_rtrancl)
```

I think "6.4.3 Fundamental methods and attributes" is also relevant because it describes how the basic methods interact with incoming facts. Notably, the '-'  noop which is sometimes used when starting proofs turns forward chaining into assumptions on the goal.

```
  with `(y,x)∈ r^*` show "(z,x) ∈ r^*"
    apply -
    apply (rule converse_rtrancl_into_rtrancl; assumption)
    done
```

This works because the first `apply` consumes all chained facts so the second apply is pure backwards chaining. This is also why the `subgoal_tac` or `rotate_tac` worked, but only if they are in seperate apply commands.